# OpenVPN does not work on MacOS

Tags: vpn

I followed [this guide](https://developernote.com/2022/10/openvpn-in-a-docker-container/) to install VPN on my Ubuntu VPS.

It works on Windows with OpenVPN client, but does not work on MacOS.

On MacOS I was even unable to do

```
ping google.com
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: See [here](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-client-vpn-tunnel-connectivity/) for more info.

Comment: @Thinkr The only log that I found is `/private/var/log/ovpnagent.log`, but it does not contain some errors. (Did `sudo grep -i err ovpnagent.log`)